# Create a ready to use install package on linux with cmake or gcc, including shred dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake

I have completed a small project that uses several libraries. the `CMakeList.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(tf_ct_log C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
include_directories(include /usr/local/include/hiredis /usr/include/openssl)
link_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
set(HDR include/ct_logger.h)
add_executable(tf_ct_logger src/main.c src/ct_logger.c ${HDR})
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_library(PostgreSQL  REQUIRED)
find_library(jansson REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(tf_ct_logger OpenSSL::SSL jansson pthread pq)
```

I would like to be able to build a package that can be installed in another machine, without downloading any dependencies. with `ldd`, I 've got all dependencies of the application and copied those files (`libxyz.so...`) into a subdirectory `deps` in my project. How can I create that package using those dependencies so that the end user will just use the object files of my project along with the dependencies libraries to create the executable?

Comment: What do you mean by "**package**"? For obtaining `.rpm` or `.tar` archive, use CPack (read its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CPack.html) about proper using).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I was thinking about just a compilation of files (excluding source code files) I can provide to a user in order to generate the application without having to download and install dependencies. Everything must be included in the "package" and configured by a script.

Comment: PhoenixBlue, you still haven't answered the question.  It looks like you are thinking a tarball would do the job for you but you might need to generate a rpm and/or a .deb . You need to understand that the system on which your program is going to run might not have all the dependencies . As @Tsyvarev mentioned, you need to look into CPack to define what all you need to pack and generate rpm and deb. Good news in you can generate both using a single spec file

Comment: `Everything must be included in the "package" and configured by a script.` - What **script** you are talking about? Is it `XXXConfig.cmake` script, which is consumed by `find_package` in the user's CMake project? Or what? Currently the question is unclear to me.

Comment: Downvoters and close voters - calm down! This topic is not 100% industrialized for native packages deployment yet. Even to ask a question correctly you need to be quite deep in the subject.

Comment: @bobah: Eh? If no one can understand the question, then it has no sense for the site. By close vote we don't blame the asker for its failing to ask the question, we blame the *question*. Even your understanding doesn't coincide with the author's one, according to the answers (yours and the asker's).

Answer (score 2):

It gets really hairy real quick when you need to create a native package for multiple flavors of installers (Debian, RH, Arch, etc.), especially if customization is involved.

If you just need a clean reproducible to get it on a box and run -- I would strongly suggest looking towards packaging it as a [Docker](https://docker.io) container.

You start from some lightweight Linux distro container ([Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) is the latest trend), derive it into one with C and C++ runtime and anything else you depend on and call this "my prod container". From that you derive one with C++ compiler and debugger installed and call it "my dev container".

We actually wrote a [little memo](https://github.com/vanilla-rtb/vanilla-rtb/blob/master/docker/README.md) a while back, while making our open source hobby usable for others.

You will probably still need to clean up your CMake file to an extent that the "install" target works (mine is [here](https://github.com/mrbald/ufw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)).

Answer (score 0):

I may have not expressed myself correctly. I just wanted to compile and build executables from my project, then find a way to copy it on another machine without having to install all dependencies before running the app.

The solution I found (with the help of a more experienced developer) was as follows:

1- Get all dependencies using `ldd`

2- Copy dependencies in a directory `dependencies`

3- On the target environment, copy content of `dependencies` into `/usr/local/lib/myapp/`

4-  On the target environment, goto `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

5- create the file `myapp.conf` with one line in it: `/usr/local/lib/myapp`

6- run `ldconfig`

Then, the executable I created on my development machine runs here smoothly!

Of course all the steps I described up there must be listed in a script for automation

Comment: Some part of this post should be incorporated to the question post, as it describes your **problem**. Please, [edit] the question, and add more explanations into it. According to "... without having to install all dependencies before running the app.", it seems that you want to not *pollute* the system with files related only to your application. But given steps are failed to do that: while they don't install the libraries, they technically install `myapp.conf` file (placing the file into system directory like `/usr/local/lib`, where only root can write, is nothing else but *installation*).